# What's the fastest route to mine Pure Essence?

Tags: runescape

I need to mine a couple thousand pure essence. What is the fastest route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a member, the fastest location is the Magician's Guild in Yanille.  If you are only free to play, the fastest location is Varrock.

Comment: How is Yanille faster?  Is it closer to a bank?  I'm guessing he's a member since he's talking about "pure" essence.

Comment: Much closer.  The front door of the guild and the front door of the bank basically face each other.  The fastest location of anything in RuneScape is the location of that thing that is closest to a bank.

Comment: Note that this requires level 66 Magic to enter.  You can also get 100/150 noted pure essence per day from Wizard Cromperty for completing the Ardougne medium/hard achievement diary or tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The Grand Exchange may be your fastest route if your mining level isn't very high and you have another way to make money quickly.